# How to solve the depend on MongoDB as Maven

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

```
com.mongodb.MongoClient //is not exists

public class MonGoDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //mongodb Connection Client.
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a [pom](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) to your project and add the required dependency to it?

Comment: just add the dependency into you `pom.xml` file. this will add the required jar to your external libraries automatically. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for you help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

**First** make sure that you have a [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.8.0) in your pom.xml :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Second** to use `com.mongodb.MongoClient` you have in your class you have to import it like so :

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class MonGoDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    }
}
```